# Testing procedural code

Tags: php, tdd

90% of our code is linear in nature. We have functions spread around in some places, but our code generally looks like this:

```
<?php

// gather some data
// do something with that data
// instantiate a bunch of globals

// output a bunch of stuff to the browser

include_once "file.php";

// output some more stuff
include_once "file2.php";

// ad nauseum
```

then in file.php

```
<?php

// do something with the globals from above
// gather some more data
// do something with this newfound data
// output more stuff to the browser
```

As part of moving to a cleaner code base, I want to begin testing this, but I'm unsure as to the proper way to do that. Any suggestions? I'm at a loss as to the proper method.

Comment: I think this is generally called 'procedural' code

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys thanks. For some reason, I couldn't come up with that on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have commented, you've essentially written procedural code. That type of code is *typically* not very conducive to Unit Testing or Test Driven Development. To begin with, you should probably become familiar with Object Oriented Programming and start grouping related pieces of functionality into appropriate abstractions.

You could try looking for [Link Seams](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=3) and other such tricks, but you're likely in for a world of hurt unless you start changing the paradigm. Unless you can break your procedural PHP into enough tiny files with set input and output points that you can test each in isolation. But that will definitely require creating methods and eliminating as many of the GLOBALS as possible.

The first thing you need to do is probably read Chapter 19 of Michael Feathers' [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052). In fact, read the whole book. Because the "seemingly simple bit" of adding tests is going to require a paradigm shift.

Comment: +1 for recommending Michael Feathers book. I should have added that to my answer. It's a must-read in situations like this.

Comment: @liquorvicar Earned an upvote from me as well. That book worth a good amount of gold.

Answer (score 1):

Fellow coders, 
Although I agree with using Selenium and such...I'd like to point this out:
We are speaking about TDD.
In my humble experience, TDD is something you catch, like the flu.
First, object oriented programming must be grasped, then unit-testing must be learned.

I'll call unit-testing: "test after"...while test after is a bit silly from a design standpoint, it will help you learn that you must switch from unit testing as an aside, to unit testing as the center of your object oriented analysis and design.

At this point, you'll be beginning TDD.

I'm sad to say it, but unless you're a phenomenally devoted person, I believe you are looking at a couple of years to get a grasp on all this...and I'm being generous.

Please do not interpret this as a slight to your character, nor skill set...but working as a programmer (paying your bills with source code) and achieving craftsmanship is not easy as it sometimes collides with business goals.

In short, depending on the business model of your organization, you may or may not be afforded adequate scheduling.  But you must press on.

Fear not, for through perseverance you can one day be able to explain this very thing to the next young chap or lady trying to step into TDD.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

[Extract Method](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractMethod.html) and [Extract Class](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractClass.html) refactorings. The comments are hints telling you what to name these methods/classes.

For test frameworks, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#PHP

Comment: I'd say this is fair, though too general to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

TDD means tests come first. You don't need to test the existing code, you have to test the new one. It's unit testing after all - it tests piece of code and not the whole page. To make sure everything works the same way it was before the refactoring, you need to write another type of tests - functional ones. Basically emulate HTTP requests and check the responses. Such tests can be build with selenium for example, and some PHP frameworks like symfony provide own server-side testing framework for this.

Comment: TDD can also be applied to legacy code. It often should be, incrementally. It is unprofessional to just say "well, that legacy code is there, and will forever remain untested by naught but system (functional) tests."

Comment: "first the developer writes a failing automated test case that defines a desired improvement or new function, then produces code to pass that test and finally refactors the new code to acceptable standards.". Writing tests is not the same as test DRIVEN development and no one says you should not write tests for existing code. Unit tests can be applied to each function. But not to the main code, which is not encapsulated in a function, and has side-effects.

Comment: I highly recommend you check out Michael Feathers book. While your technical definition of TDD is correct, it misses the point of getting a legacy system under control through adding tests:


`The Legacy Code Change Algorithm
When you have to make a change in a legacy code base, here is an algorithm you can use.

Identify change points.

Find test points.

Break dependencies.

Write tests.

Make changes and refactor.
--Working Effectively With Legacy Code Chapter 2`

Answer (score 0):

I don't envy you. I've been where you are (and still am!) and it's not a good place. Short of a complete rewrite of your codebase it's not going to be an easy path. Ideally you need to refactor to get your code under test but ideally you should have your code under test before you refactor - Catch 22.  If you have a load of functions, you might be able to get these under test using one of the available testing frameworks (testing frameworks don't work only with OO code!). Another strategy you could use would be to get bits of your code under test using web-testing (using something like [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29)). You can at least get your code into some sort of test harness to give some confidence as you refactor the code towards something more testable.

Comment: Getting the code into a test harness is definitely a good first step. Nice approaches for this in the beginning may be to apply Wrap Methods which internally include (in effect achieving delegation) to the PHP code.

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions any specific suggestions on how to do that, considering the example above?

Comment: It is perfectly valid to start writing Selenium tests to get some kind of basis that you're not mucking everything up, as other commenters have said. I just wouldn't leave it at that.

Extract Method and Extract Class are foundations that will help get you moving in the right direction, though you'll probably want to start with Wrap Method. This video explains the logic of Wrap Method. http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/134 With .php files, you can start by creating new php files with functions that include the legacy files, as seen in http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

Getting procedural code under test is a nightmare, but an incremental approach is possible.  Consider this:

```
// bar.php
$priceWithoutTax = 10;
$priceWithTax = 10 * $annoyingGlobalVarWithTaxRateInIt;
echo $priceWithTax;
```

You should aim in the first instance to get as far as:

```
//bar.php
echo Foo::getPriceWithTax($annoyingGlobalVarWithTaxRateInIt);

//Foo.php
class Foo {
    public static function getPriceWithTax($annoyingGlobalVarWithTaxRateInIt) {
        $priceWithoutTax = 10;
        $priceWithTax = 10 * $annoyingGlobalVarWithTaxRateInIt;
        return $priceWithTax;
    }
}

//FooTest.php
public function testGetPriceWithTax() {
    $expectedResult = 12;
    $taxRate = 1.2;
    $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, Foo::getPriceWithTax($taxRate));
}
```

It might not be the way you want the code to *end up*, but sticking the main body of the code in a static function has here at least enabled us to get the actual business logic (here a trivial calculation) under test.

The purpose of this, assuming your code occasionally does something more complicated than multiplying things by 10, is to allow safe refactoring.  You can now make changes to the *implementation* of the calculation (which, for more complex business logic than this, should probably involve proper object orientation ;-) ), safe in the knowledge that your tests will tell you if you have broken anything.

In general, you would always aim for an incremental approach to applying unit tests and refactoring.  Get part of your code to the point where it is testable with minimum possible changes to production code, then get it under test, then do more extensive refactoring to the part you're working on, then move on to the next bit.

Good luck.